# Swift/iOS: Tap Gesture to find which text field just became the first responder

Tags: ios, swift

I have 11 tap gesture recognizers embedded into 11 out of 100 textfields. These textfields are all stored in an array called boxArray.

My goal is that when 1 of the 11 textfields is tapped, I would like to know which textfield just became the first responder. Here is what I have...

```
@objc func tappedTextField(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    for i in 0...99 {
        if (boxArray[i]?.isFirstResponder)! {
            if let index = boxArray.index(of: boxArray[i]) {
            print(index)
            break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that when a textfield is tapped. This function is printing whoever the last first responder was, not who just became the first responder. So if I'm at current first responder textfield 13, and I tap textfield index 52 to become the first responder. It will print 13.

I need to use the tap functionality here, so I can't get rid of it in favor for text delegates.

I could accomplish this if I could pass in the textField that was tapped into this function and then force it to become the first responder before I run the rest of the block, but I don't think there is a way to pass it in.

Is there any other way to make this work with tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: Isn't this a repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177364/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-a-text-field-not-as-expected)?

Comment: I tried to use the solutions from my previous question but they weren't producing the result I was looking for

Comment: Then post comments on those answers as needed. Edit your previous question as needed to provide any additional details. That's better than reposting the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to compare gestureView , as the responder is not yet to be assigned to the recent clicked textfield or use Tag

```
@objc func tappedTextField(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    for i in 0...99 {
        if  ( boxArray[i] == sender.view ) {
            if let index = boxArray.index(of: boxArray[i]) {
            print(index)
            break
            }
        }
    }
}
```